# How do I make a checkbox form initially have all options checked?

Tags: 7

I have a drupal form in a module that doesn't pull in information until submitted.  Can I make the checkboxes initially checked?

```
  $form['search_block_type'] = array(
    '#description' => "Select content types",
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#title' => t('Content types'),
    '#default_value' => $default_types,
  );
```

I assumed it was #checked' => 'yes' but that doesn't seem to work.(from a view)

Comment: What exactly is inside `$options`? How you prepared it? Have you tried `'#default_value' => array_keys($options)`?

Comment: That worked!   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The actual form element values when selected are always the keys of what you have inside `$options`. You also can see that when inspecting the markup. So simply use `'#default_value' => array_keys($options)` to have all options preselected.

```
$form['search_block_type'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => t('Content types'),
  '#description' => t('Select content types'),
  '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => array_keys($options),
];
```